# Python tkinter, grid manager is not working

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Insert title")
root.configure(background='#CCCCFF')
label1 = Label(root, text = "Insert title", font = ("Rockwell", 12))
label2 = Label(root, text = "Name", font = ("Rockwell", 25))
label1.configure(background='#CCCCFF')
label2.configure(background = '#CCCCFF')
label1.grid(row = 8, column = 3)
root.mainloop()
```

Every time I change the settings for the grid manager for label2, the label always stays in the same place. How can I fix this?

Comment: _"Every time I change the settings for the grid manager for label2..."_ Where are you doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking "why does my 'Insert title' label always appear in the upper left corner, even though it has large row and column values?", it's because totally empty rows and columns are squashed down to zero pixels, so the eighth row will appear to be the first row, if rows 1 through 7 don't have any widgets in them.

One possible workaround is to add placeholder widgets to each row and column that you don't want to collapse.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Insert title")
root.configure(background='#CCCCFF')

for i in range(10):
    Frame(root, width=20, height=20, background='#CCCCFF').grid(row=0, column=i)

for j in range(10):
    Frame(root, width=20, height=20, background='#CCCCFF').grid(column=0, row=j)

label1 = Label(root, text = "Insert title", font = ("Rockwell", 12))
label2 = Label(root, text = "Name", font = ("Rockwell", 25))
label1.configure(background='#CCCCFF')
label2.configure(background = '#CCCCFF')
label1.grid(row = 8, column = 3)
label2.grid(row = 9, column = 3)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

if a row or column is completely empty, it's size will be zero. So even though you put something in row 8, rows zero through seven are non-existent. The same goes for the columns.